# Amazon S3 Query String Authentication Invalid Date

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I found this script for creating links to Amazon S3 resources using the Query String Authentication: https://gist.github.com/1032395

Since I'm not using rails I included the libraries manually.

Everytime I try opening a resource using an URL generated by this script I get an "access denied"-error because of a "Invalid date (should be seconds since epoch): 1349364847"

Any ideas where this could come from?

```
require 'cgi'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

def generate_secure_s3_url(s3_key)
    #
    # s3_key would be a path (including filename) to the file like:  "folder/subfolder/filename.jpg"
    # but it should NOT contain the bucket name or a leading forward-slash
    #
    # this was built using these instructions:
    # http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html
    # http://aws.amazon.com/code/199?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

    s3_base_url       = '' # i.e. https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com
    bucket            = '' # i.e. mybucket
    access_key_id     = '' # your Amazon S3 access key ID
    secret_access_key = '' # your Amazon S3 secret access key
    expiration_date   = Time.now.utc.to_i + (2*24*60*60) # 2 days from now in UTC epoch time (i.e. 1308172844)

    # this needs to be formatted exactly as shown below and UTF-8 encoded
    string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n#{expiration_date}\n/#{bucket}/#{s3_key}".encode("UTF-8")

    # we have to CGI/URL escape the signature since it would fail if it included / or + characters
    signature = CGI.escape(Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret_access_key, string_to_sign)).gsub("\n",""))

    return "#{s3_base_url}/#{s3_key}?AWSAccessKeyId=#{access_key_id}
                                    &Expires=#{expiration_date}
                                    &Signature=#{signature}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you `require 'active_support/core_ext'` you can use `2.days.from_now.utc.to_i`

I wrestled with this for a bit and eventually settled on aws-sdk:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method

```
require 'aws-sdk'

bucket = "bucketname"
resource = "myfile.jpg"
access_key_id = "12345"
secret_access_key = "abcdef"

s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => access_key_id, :secret_access_key = secret_access_key)
signed_url = s3.buckets[bucket].objects[resource].url_for(:read).to_s
```

Note: `url_for` also takes an `:expires` option, the default being one hour.